# React component rendering too many times?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch, state

I've got a react app using ReduxToolkit and React.useState in the App component.

It's written to attempt a token refresh on the first render. Then, based on the auth state after refresh, either render the desired route or render the signin route (not using redirects, just state and conditional rendering)

My expectation is that upon heading to the homepage ('/'), useEffect triggers, attempts token refresh, dispatches the token/user credentials, `setLoading(false)`, then renders the homepage `('/')` if successful, or the login page if not successful.

The problem is, it seems to be rendering the  component a few times while it's performing the token refresh, before it's even received the refresh result, causing it to flicker to the login page, then to the main dashboard, when it should just be a loadscreen, then the main dashboard.

I feel like the `setLoading(false)` paired with the redux dispatch could be causing multiple re-renders but I don't understand why the re-rendering would happen BEFORE the refresh request has happened.

StrictMode is not being used, I understand it renders the page twice in order to show data on problems it detects.

The loading state defaults to true, so first render should always be a loadscreen/fullscreen spinner.

The console contents when I refresh the page at '/', where the routes are logged from its respective RouteProtector component (Protect.tsx)

```
UseEffect refresh                               App.tsx:47 
render                                          App.tsx:20 
attempting refresh of access token              App.tsx:22 
refresh token in localStorage                   App.tsx:24 
/                                               Protect.tsx:15 
/signin                                         Protect.tsx:15 
refresh success                                 App.tsx:39 
/signin                                         Protect.tsx:15 
/                                               Protect.tsx:15
```

App.tsx:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import SignUpView from "./views/auth/SignUpView";
import SignInView from "./views/auth/SignInView";
import Protect from "./components/auth/Protect";
import { useAppDispatch } from "./hooks/store";
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import DashboardView from "./views/DashboardView";
import UserListView from "./views/users/UserListView";
import EditUserView from "./views/users/EditUserView";
import UserDetailView from "./views/users/UserDetailView";
import { setCredentials } from "./features/auth/authSlice";
import { RefreshResponse } from "./models/Auth";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const refresh = async () => {
    console.log("render")
    const token = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
    console.log("attempting refresh of access token")
    if (token) {
      console.log("refresh token in localStorage")
      const refreshRequest = {
        refresh: token,
      };

      const response = await fetch(
        "http://my.api.com/auth/refresh/",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(refreshRequest),
        }
      );

      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("refresh success");
        const data: RefreshResponse = await response.json();
        dispatch(setCredentials({ user: data.user, token: data.accessToken }));
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("UseEffect refresh")
    refresh();
    setLoading(false)
  }, []);

  if (loading) return (
    <div className="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-dark">
      <Spinner animation="border" />
    </div>
  );

  // the route prop on the Protect components below is just for debugging, it gets printed when rendered


  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <Protect route="/">
              <DashboardView />
            </Protect>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/signup"
          element={
            <Protect route="/signup" inverse>
              <SignUpView />
            </Protect>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/signin"
          element={
            <Protect route="/signin" inverse>
              <SignInView />
            </Protect>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/users"
          element={
            <Protect route="/users">
              <UserListView />
            </Protect>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/users/:id"
          element={
            <Protect route="/users:id">
              <UserDetailView />
            </Protect>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/users/:id/edit"
          element={
            <Protect route="/users/:id/edit">
              <EditUserView />
            </Protect>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
      );
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Protect.tsx:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { User } from "../../models/User";
import { useTypedSelector } from "../../hooks/store";

interface IProtectProps {
  inverse?: boolean;
  staff?: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactElement;
  route?: string
}

const Protect: React.FC<IProtectProps> = ({ children, inverse, staff, route }) => {
  const user = useTypedSelector((state) => state.auth.user) as User;
  console.log(route);

  if (staff)
    return <>{user && user.is_staff ? children : <Navigate to="/" />}</>;

  if (!inverse) return <>{user ? children : <Navigate to="/signin" />}</>;
  return <>{user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : children}</>;
};

export default Protect;
```

Comment: I just had a quick look at the code. I see you have a useEffect that runs on mount (empty dependency array) which sets loading to false. Since it initially has value true, it's going to cause a re-render. I would have set it to initially false, and then change it to true as soon as you start fetching.

Comment: Actually I ended up moving the setLoading(false) line to a different location within the refresh() function and that solved the problem, only two renders rather than the original 5 I was experiencing. Strange though because that's where I initially had it, at least I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by moving the `setLoading(false)` line to the end of the `refresh()` function. I'm still a little confused as this is how I originally had it before moving it after the `refresh()` function inside the `useEffect()` call.

I also changed the useEffect dependency to `dispatch`. The app now only renders twice, once for the loadscreen while it refreshes the token, and then once for the actual page render that's desired.

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("UseEffect refresh")
    const refresh = async () => {
      console.log("render");
      const token = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
      console.log("attempting refresh of access token");
      if (token) {
        console.log("refresh token in localStorage");
        const refreshRequest = {
          refresh: token,
        };

        const response = await fetch(
          "http://jrapi.subspacedev.io/auth/refresh/",
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(refreshRequest),
          }
        );

        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log("refresh success");
          const data: RefreshResponse = await response.json();
          dispatch(
            setCredentials({ user: data.user, token: data.accessToken })
          );
        }
        
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    refresh();
  }, [dispatch]);
```